# Как stack overflow получает прибыль?

Tags: поддержка, stackoverflow, stackexchange

Рекламы я тут не видел.
Модераторы и сотрудники компании тоже получают з.п.?

Comment: Ну "помощники" - это сами пользователи, поэтому я, как пользователь, не получаю ЗП от SE, ибо не сотрудник компании. А так - любопытный  вопрос.

Comment: Почему у вас поставлены кавычки на слове "помощники"? По [правилам русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/53-kav1) получается, что использовано ироническое значение (для серьёзно заданного вопроса это не очень уместно), либо вы хотите подчеркнуть, что эти помощнички не особо и помогают? Вопрос хороший, а кавычки предлагаю убрать.

Comment: @AK Я могу убрать, если хотите, но "помощники" это люди которые отвечают на вопросы просто так, и  другие люди, например дизайнеры, разработчики(они же не помогают) - откуда -то они получают зарплату?

Comment: Модератор - гражданин с активной гражданской позицией. Волонтёр в сфере выгребания мусора. А эти Ваши "помощники" - сотрудники компании, те, кто создаёт эту платформу. Не стоит их сравнивать.

Comment: Неа, модераторы получают только ромб и сувенирную кружку. Сотрудники, конечно же, получают зарплату. Источник дохода компании — реклама вакансий на Stack Overflow на английском. Вроде есть ещё Stack Exchange Enterprise для компаний, желающих получить собственный сайт вопросов и ответов, но я не знаю, какой процент доходов компании он составляет.

Comment: @AK сначала подумал что вы про уборщиков сказали))))

Comment: @NickVolynkin, это сколько надо вакансий, чтобы покрыть работу и получить прибыль?

Comment: @Other, enSO весьма популярен и вакансий хватает :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Что-то я не очень понял про вакансии. Что значит "реклама вакансий"?

Comment: [Статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/285478/) по теме.

Comment: [How We Make Money at Stack Overflow: 2016 Edition](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/How-We-Make-Money-at-Stack-Overflow-2016-Edition/)